# Telerik.Web.Ui - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Have stuck with this one for 2 days now.

I have a web application using asp.net with telerik controls.
There is a register page that has various "subpages" content loaded via Telerik.Web.UI. So when i navigate from page 2 to 3 and vice verca for about 20 times i get this message.

`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

[image]

I did my research and i searched for dublicate js files but i didnt find anything suspicious.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue with handlers to the Sys.Application.Load event. Are you adding handlers inside the handlers, for example, that could cause a recursion?

Also, disable the RadScriptManager script combination (`EnableScriptCombine="false"`) to clearly see which script it is (it seems like the core MS AJAX though).